# How to show a div when a filtered list is empty (Filtered using ng-repeat with ng-if)

Tags: angularjs

I have a div with ng-repeat, filtered with ng-if.. Its works fine.. so what i need to do to make appear a div when list filter returns no objects??

The div

```
<div class="item listItem active" ng-repeat="u in users | filter: inputFilter" ng-if="u.reports.length>0">
    Name: {{u.name}}
    Reports: {{u.reports.length}}
</div>
```

I want to show a div with a message "We dont have reported users yet!" sometimes we will not have users with reports, so, i need to show this div.

PS* I have used the search..!

------------ EDIT: Improving the Question ------------

Im not using the inputFilter to show the list
A list with all users will be loaded in `users` but i will show only the users with a report list inside `u.reports` using `ng-if="u.reports.length>0"`

The same "users" list will be used in another div, so i cant filter all the PS* list showing just reported users.

------------ IMPLEMENTED SOLUTION ------------

I have created a var to set a counter, incrementing by every iteration and decremented every time when i remove an item from the list.

Comment: can you share how your user data look like ?

Comment: I was confused about what you are trying to accomplish, but I think I've figured it out now. See if the answer I provided addresses the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to detect the condition where all users in your list have **no** reports and then display a message. If that is the case I think you are going to need to resort to a function in your controller because `ng-if` and `ng-show` have limited expression support. Here is a sample of how you could write a simple function that returns `true` if any of the users have at least one report and `false` if all of the users have zero reports. Then you can use the function in your `ng-if` to show or hide the message. I added a button that will push a report onto one of the users so you can verify that the code is properly showing and hiding the message as appropriate.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.users = [{
      name: 'Adam',
      reports: []
    }, {
      name: 'Alan',
      reports: []
    }, {
      name: 'Allen',
      reports: []
    }, {
      name: 'Amy',
      reports: []
    }, {
      name: 'Andrea',
      reports: []
    }];

    $scope.noUsersWithReports = function() {
      var usersWithReports = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {
        reports: []
      });
      return usersWithReports.length === 0;
    }

    $scope.reportUser = function(user) {
      $scope.users[$scope.users.indexOf(user)].reports.push({
        name: 'Fake Report'
      });
    }
    
    $scope.clearReports = function() {
      angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user) {
        user.reports = [];
      });
    }
  });
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    <button ng-repeat="u in users" ng-click="reportUser(u)">Report {{u.name}}</button>
    <button ng-click="clearReports()">Clear All Reports</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    Filter:
    <input type="text" ng-model="listFilter">
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="u in users | filter: listFilter as filteredList" ng-if="u.reports.length > 0">
    Name: {{u.name}}
    <br/>Reports: {{u.reports.length}}
  </div>
  <div ng-if="noUsersWithReports()">
    We don't have reported users yet!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add usersFiltered list and try this one :

```
<div class="item listItem active" ng-repeat="u in usersFiltered = (users | filter: inputFilter)" ng-if="usersFiltered.length>0">
Name: {{u.name}}
Reports: {{u.reports.length}}
```

Comment: Your code will work when i type something in the <input ng-model="inputFilter" /> but when i filter the list over the ng-if, will not work :/

Answer (score 0):

Set a new parameter in ng-repeat which will have the filtered list then you can simply check that list for your purpose!

```
<div class="item listItem active" ng-repeat="u in filteredUsers =( users| filter:query) " ng-hide="u.reports.length>0">
        Name: {{u.name}}
        Reports: {{u.reports.length}}
</div>


<div ng-if="filterdedUsres.length === 0">
No user found
</div>
```